# how to define a model which is an array (not in database!)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller

I want to store data from form named "adding" in an array - I want to generate other form depending on the data from this array so I think that I don't have to use database here (am I wrong?). How I should define an array in "adding"'s model?This is how my form looks like:

```
<h2>Add new data</h2>
Please select, what kind of data you want to add:<br /><br />
<%= simple_form_for :adding do |f| %>

  <%= f.input :first_name, :collection => 0..10 , :prompt => "How many?" %>

  <%= f.input :last_name, :collection => 0..10 , :prompt => "How many?" %>

  <%= f.input :city, :collection => 0..10 , :prompt => "How many?" %>

  <%= f.input :postal, :collection => 0..10 , :prompt => "How many?" %>

  <%= f.input :street, :collection => 0..10 , :prompt => "How many?" %>

  <%= f.input :job, :collection => 0..10 , :prompt => "How many?" %>

  <%= f.input :role, :collection => 0..10 , :prompt => "How many?" %>

  <%= f.button :submit, 'next step', :style => "margin-top: 20px;" %>
<% end %>
```

Please help :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you click on the submit button you will pass the values from the input as parameters to the action and controller you define. You can process and do some work in that action and then render the new form that will be created depending of the input from before.

Comment: problem with this basic approach is validation. And in general it's better to have slim controllers and thus extract logic within the model

Answer (score 1):

[Check this railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/219-active-model), it's a great live example.

And remember: in Ruby, you don't have to type variables.